# Character set to send UK pound £ symbol to html client with webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, encoding

In the database I have a NVARCHAR(100) field which has a **UK £** symbol. I added the following in the **web.config** of the **WebAPI** application:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization 
         requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In the html page, I added the following to the head of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

I expected the **£** to display correctly, but does not. It shows as **?**

On the client side, I can't use string replace to replace the encoded **£** to **&pound** because I have so many content with this symbol.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

This is what I still see �. As per this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29) it is a REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. I copied the text in notepad.exe and tried to save as unicode html page, apply the ISO-8859-1 charset which also did not help.

Comment: Can you confirm what encoding the pound sign was when you saved it?

Comment: I don't know what encoding being used. What I see in the database is £, not any other characters. Until the exit location of the WebAPI where the response is created, I see £ in the content. After that it turns to a question mark in a black diamond like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to using the correct character set of **UTF-8**. WebAPI by default uses utf-8.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcdGVtcFxUZXN0UG91bmRcVGVzdFBvdW5kXEFwaVxWYWx1ZXNcMQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 21:25:24 GMT
Content-Length: 13
```

The response like above show the charset as **utf-8**. However, this can be overridden by using custom **MediaTypeFormatter**. I had a custom **MediaTypeFormatter** which was manipulating the data before sent to the client. After the custom formatter was removed, I can see the **£** in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use utf-8.

```
 <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Comment: I use AngularJS **{{:: vm.Content}}** to display the content. **vm.Content** is a JSON string which is returned from the WebAPI.